# PHP SOAP client invalid actor

Tags: php, soap

I've never worked with SOAP before. I have got everything to work, but I get a PHP warning in the errors log.

Warning:

```
[05-Nov-2015 11:06:06 UTC] PHP Warning:  SoapHeader::SoapHeader(): 
Invalid actor in
C:\www\srf.cdab.eu\wp-content\themes\mypage\includes\soap.php on line 61
```

soap.php:61

```
$objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security',> $objSoapVarHeaderVal, true, NULL);
```

I've googled and haven't find anything that explains why I get this error. What could be the reason of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

The Actor musst be a URI-String or SOAP_ACTOR_NONE.

```
$objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security', $objSoapVarHeaderVal, true, SOAP_ACTOR_NONE);
```

or

```
$objSoapVarWSSEHeader = new SoapHeader($strWSSENS, 'Security', $objSoapVarHeaderVal, true, 'https://yourdomain/yourservice');
```